# How to rollback from Azure Paas to Iaas mssql with minimal downtime?

Tags: mysql, azure-sql-database, paas, iaas

I will be migrating databases from Azure IaaS infrastructure using mssql to Azure SQL. After migration I need a method to efficiently rollback to IaaS infrastructure if issues are encountered minutes/hours after migration.

It's possible to export databases in Azure SQL but is this the recommended method for moving back from PaaS to IaaS or on-prem? There will likely have only been a small amount of transactions in this window of time so making a full export seems like it will take a long time.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Back in september one of my customers requested me exactly the same, a rollback plan in case they wanted to go back to the SQL Server VM IaaS from Azure SQL Database PaaS, for say a week later after migrating.

What I found is that it is easy to migrate to PaaS and not so easy to return back to IaaS. Unfortunately, the best, quickest, and predictable method to rollback is to export the Azure SQL Database, move the bacpac to a local disk to the VM and import the bacpac using latest version of SQL Server Management Studio. Doing this I found to obstacles which are documented [here](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting213.htm) and [here](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting214.htm).